# Find the Vo at Vs = 10V?

Tags: diodes

[image]

In the above Question, I am not able to judge the states of the Diode when Vs is at 10V.

Can somebody can explain me, how we can proceed in order to find the Vout.

Comment: For the different voltage configurations you need to make an assumption about which diodes are conducting, then write KVL equations. Check for the diode "on" condition at the end. If the currents you find lead to correct operating conditions you're good. If not, then you assumed a diode was conducting that wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

D1: is off (cathode +10V, no way to get 0.7V from A to C)

D2: assuming D4 is off, 10V across the branch --> Diode is on, will result in 0.7V across the diode the rest will drop across the two 10k resistors. (9.3V / 2 = 4.65V across each resistor)

D3: is on, C 0.7V below the input at 9.3V

D4: Output is at 4.65V, C is at 9.3V --> Diode is off (assumption was OK)